# Landscape mode is broken for some Views in iOS7.works fine for iOS8?

Tags: ios7, uiview, ios8, landscape

[image: in iOS7 displaying view in Portrait]

In ios8 app is working fine.But in ios7 some views are displaying in portrait mode
how can i resolve this?